# How to start using Twitter Bootstrap and Sass in a Sinatra project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sinatra, sass

I know Twitter Bootstrap is written in Less, but there are a bunch of Sass versions as well. I am having a hard time figuring out the best one to use and how to set up my Sinatra project.

I want my assets to be pre-compiled and fingerprinted in a production environment but have the uncompressed assets in development so I can debug easier (like the Rails asset pipeline). I tried setting up [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass), but it requires Compass. But I don't really need compass when I've got all the twitter bootstrap mixins. I also had trouble configuring it.

Anyway, a definitive answer on what I should do would be helpful.

Comment: why don't you just use the compiled versions of bootstrap? You're not changing much of it, do you? You can still use a sass version of your very own css files to adapt bootstrap to your needs.

Comment: I do want to override Twitter Bootstrap defaults by setting a variable for my fonts, colors, etc like it's mentioned in their less documentation. Otherwise I will look like every other site using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Plugin/Rack.html

Answer (score 5):

I just use env-dependent tags in my layout template for the .less version of bootstrap, or my recompiled .css version:

```
<% if settings.development? %>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/less/style.less">
    <%= javascript_tag "/js/libs/less-1.2.1.min.js" %>
<% end %>

<% if settings.production? %>
    <%= stylesheet_tag "/css/mycss.css" %>
<% end %>
```

This way it just shows me the on-the-fly version in development, and the .css file in production mode. When I deploy I just compile the stylesheets on the command line.

```
$ lessc public/less/style.less > public/css/mycss.css
```

(In that example I'm also using https://github.com/wbzyl/sinatra-static-assets/ to timestamp the css file for production.)

public/less/style.less starts off just something like:

```
 @import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

 @import "bootstrap/responsive.less";
```

And all the bootstrap .less files live at public/less/bootstrap/

Basically just drop all of https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/less in there.

And you can then start over-riding things yourself in the same file, importing other files you've made, or editing the actual core bootstrap files (:|)

If you really have to use sass (I don't see why this should be the case, see comment) it isn't quite as simple as there isn't a standard .js compiler to easily include in your layout.

I guess you could try telling rack to use http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Plugin/Rack.html in your config.ru when you're running in development mode. I've never tried that though, and I had trouble with the .less rack plugin  the one time I tried to use it.

Comment: BTW, in my opinion going to trouble to use a sass version of bootstrap is pointless. You're using bootstrap to get a standardised set of sensible defaults and tools. Those defaults and tools are built in less. Less and sass are just two convenient marcos for generating css. They're not that different, and they're both really easy. So just use the one that is best supported by the libraries you're using (less in this case).

Comment: Can you show an example of what your style.less file looks like?

Comment: When you start it will be just a call to the rest of the bootstrap .less files. `@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less"; @import "bootstrap/responsive.less";` All the other .less files live in `public/less/bootstrap/`.